# How do I Change String Array into Char Array?

Tags: c++, arrays

Okay. I have taken a sentence and split into an array thus far with this code I found online:

```
    string strWords[5];
    short counter = 0;

    for(short i =0; i<texttoChange.length();i++)
    {
        strWords[counter] +=texttoChange[i];
        if(texttoChange[i] == ' ')
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    for(short i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cout << strWords[i] << "(" << strWords[i].size() << ")" << endl;
    }
```

Now I want to take strWords[i] and split that array into an array of characters or single letter string array. Is it Possible?

Comment: A `std::string` is already an array of characters internally. It has `operator[]` and `c_str()` if you really want a pointer to the array.

Comment: Try and use `std::vector` instead of fixed-length C-style arrays. You're making a wild presumption here that there is 5 and exactly 5 words. If that presumption was well-founded you'd define it as a `const` and not just sprinkle those *magic numbers* through your code.

Comment: Your `for` loop risks going out of bounds of the `strWords` array if `texttoChange` has more than 5 words in it, or more than 1 space between 2 given words. Consider changing `strWords` to a `std::vector` instead. And rather than using `operator+=` to build up each individual word 1 char at a time, consider using `std::istringstream` instead, which has an `operator>>` for reading space-delimited words.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need a c style array, you can do,

`char *charArray = strWords[i].c_str();`, you can get the size by `strlen(charArray)`

otherwise there is no point of converting string to char array.

Comment: Note that the pointer returned could become invalid anytime the string changes.